# Dilemma... jQuery, SharePoint publishing page layouts, and dynamic page properties

Tags: jquery, cewp

Dilemma: I am trying to create/edit a publishing page layout with jQuery accordions that pull in dynamic page properties. When I implement my solution, it works; however, I am no longer able to edit the page layout as I receive this error:

soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. ---> An unexpected error occurred while opening this page. For assistance, contact your site administrator.

Its an odd error: I am able to continue to create new pages using my page layout with no errors; I just cannot edit the page layout anymore.

As a workaround, I thought I would use a CEWP and insert my jQuery via a text file. This worked but my dynamic page properties does not pull in when I use a CEWP.

1. Why is SharePoint giving me an error with jQuery and page layouts?
2. Alternatively, how can I pull in SharePoint page properties in my CEWP?

In the CEWP, I am using:

```
<Sharepointwebcontrols:noteField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" runat="server"/>
```

Which worked in my page layout but does not in my CEWP.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put server side controls in a CEWP and expect it to work, it won't.

The way I've done this in page layouts is to create a hidden div and add all my field references there, each wrapped in their own div or span with a unique ID that I can hook into via jQuery. This then allows me to do what ever I need to do.